# Why logical systems?

Tags: router, juniper, juniper-srx

Juniper supports partitioning of a physical device such as a router into multiple logical systems. Each of these systems could have their independent routing/switching tables depending on the logical system type.

My question is where exactly (in the actual implemented network) would an administrator need to configure a logical system? In other words, what are the factors that trigger the creation of logical system in an actual network?

Any links to provide an insight into the same would also be appreciated.

P.S. Any idea what terminology is used by Cisco for providing logical systems?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: I would definitely recommend you to read [Logical Systems User Guide for Routers and Switches](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/logical-systems/), especially [Logical Systems Applications](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/logical-systems/topics/topic-map/security-logical-systems-for-routers-and-switches.html#id-logical-systems-applications) answers to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Logical systems are generally used in the lab as a way of doing realistic network testing on a single or smaller number of physical devices.

Having said that, I have seen Logical Systems used in production in the following ways:

- In SRX Firewalls as a way of providing multi-tenancy - each tenant is given a logical system which they can log in to and run their own security policies against their own zones without affecting other tenants (something that you cannot enforce easily with virtual-routers)
- In MX routers where a P/PE node is actually divided into a P and PE logical system when the PoP is first built, and then the roles are separated out into dedicated hardware as the node grows in a very hitless manner

Answer (score 1):

It can be routing and management separation. 
Administrator can make isolation network for guest.
Logical router apply to different rule for each team with routing level.

Cisco have SDR(Secure Domain Router).
But its required IOS-XR 
VRF is work with IOS.